# Flutter - Can't seem to order a list and i've no clue why

Tags: json, list, flutter, api

I have a model which defines some JSON from an Api.

```
abstract class ITrainingExerciseListingProvider with Store {
  @observable
  List exerciseList = [];

  @observable
  List<ExerciseModel> exerciseModelList = [];
```

If i try and put a
exerciseList.sort(); itgives a constructor error.

I'm trying to get this listview to order on the length but i'm stuck!

```
ListView.separated(
                              // itemCount: 14,
                              itemCount: sl<ITrainingExerciseListingProvider>()
                                  ?.exerciseModelList
                                  ?.length,
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
exerciseList.sort((o1, o2) {
                // handle the sort logic here
                return 1;
              });
```